# Making a universal view in Django

Tags: django, url, django-views

I wanted to ask that whether it is possible to make a view called for every single url or rather request.

Like i have a application that makes different pages for our site, now i want to display list of created lists in the navbar.

For the code refer to our [repo](https://github.com/Anurag-Ans/JHTS)

Comment: Did you try already some template include? Other thing is might to check out is template tags or  middlewares to get your data in the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think you want a `view` called for every request. You will usually have separate `view` for different urls. You might want a way to some method which should be executed from every view.

eg: You might want a particular `context` to be present in all the template. In such case you should use TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

If you only want a navbar present on all pages, you should either use template inheritance or use `include` tags. Check about `extends` and `include` tag in django templates.

Comment: Hey could you please show me an example of it, please.

Comment: I wanted to ask that whether, my custom context processor will get called for each request ?

Comment: @Anurag-Sharma Yes, if you add your custom context processor in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, it would be available as part of context in every template you render.